# How to specify JRE used for running vugen scripts in HP LoadRunner?

Tags: java, http, settings, loadrunner, vugen

For Java over HTTP, under **Replay > Run-Time Settings > Java VM**, we can specify the JDK used to compile the script:

[image]

However, how can we specify the **JRE** used run the compiled script?

(It seems to default to the specified JDK's JRE but I need to run the script using another JRE.)

**Note:** I'm using HP Vugen 12.01

Comment: @JamesPulley, I'm trying to run it using another JRE (v7), not the JDK's JRE (v6). Is there a way to specify a JRE that is not the JDK's JRE?

Comment: What you record is what you playback.  You are not engaged in functional testing, nor are you engaged in integration testing on the client.  You are testing the impact of the messages generated by the client on the server.  As the code is the same from one JRE to another, so should then be the messages generated and sent to the server, as well as the processing of the responses.

Comment: @JamesPulley, Hmm, the load generators do not have JRE v6 installed. They have v7 and v8 installed, so I need to test if the script would work on these machines.

Comment: Make your test development and test execution environments Java identical or you make your life difficult, as in this case.

Comment: @JamesPulley, Btw I see that you are active on sqa forums. Why are you not active on the official HP.com loadrunner forums?

Comment: I am active on SQAForums, Yahoo Groups, Google Groups, Facebook, LinkedIn, PerfBytes, Stackoverflow, Quora & my own company's internal support site to clients.   I think HP has enough direct site support from internal staff.

Comment: @JamesPulley, Why did you choose Stackoverflow instead of the dedicated [sqa.SE](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loadrunner) site?

Comment: Because this is where people ask questions instead of going to the dedicated SQA sites